# How to get userinfo from NSNotification in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

I got this error in swift3:

```
Cannot convert value of type [AnyHashable : Any] to type NSDictionary in coercion.
```

My Code is:

```
  func downloadProgress(notification:NSNotification){

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary
    {
         print(userInfo) // [AnyHashable("progressPercentage"): 0.82530790852915281]

      if let progressValue = userInfo["progressPercentage"] as? Float {
        if progressValue > 0.01{

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The actual userInfo value is `["progressPercentage": 0.82530790852915281]` but its printed as `[AnyHashable("progressPercentage"): 0.82530790852915281]` and not satisfying the `if` condition.

Edit:

No luck for `notification.userInfo as? [AnyHashable: Any]`, But now works for `notification.userInfo as? [String: AnyObject]` and `notification.userInfo as? [String: Any]`

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about `notification.userInfo as? [String: AnyObject]`?

Comment: Why do you need to cast it anyways?

Comment: @ozgur, casting to `[String: AnyObject]` works now

Comment: @MuruganandhamK - are you seen my answer, I clearly mentioned the point if you know the type use `[String: Any]` for swift3 , if you are used `[String: AnyObject]` this is for swift2

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, yep i used `[String: Any]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

type converson

[image]

use

```
 func downloadProgress(notification:NSNotification){

if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as [String: Any] // or use if you know the type  [AnyHashable : Any]
{
     print(userInfo) 

  if let progressValue = userInfo["progressPercentage"] as? Float {
    if progressValue > 0.01{

    }
  }
}
 }
```

for more information see this [API Reference Documents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyhashable)

Comment: Hi, @Anbu.Karthik, `[AnyHashable : Any]` is not working here. `[String: Any]` and `[String: AnyObject]` are supporting the type cast now

Comment: Accepted yours :-)

Comment: @MuruganandhamK - not like that ,

Answer (score 1):

Plase use the new class `Notification` instead of `NSNotification`.

I haven't my Mac with me, but this *should* fix the problem.

This change is applied automatically if you use the integrated Xcode Swift conversion tool.

Comment: hi @Teejay, problem is not with `Notification` or  with  `NSNotification`.   Its all about type casting

Comment: Ok, but probably if you use the conversion tool it will also convert NSDictionary to the proper `[AnyHashable : Any]` construct.

Comment: yeh, i got it. Thanks